# Do beam supporting posts need to line up from basement to roof

Tags: load-bearing, post

Do beam supporting posts need to line up across multiple levels of a house? I have a steel beam holding up the main level of my house.  In line with that beam, on the main level is a load bearing wall I wish to remove.  All posts in drawing are existing.  I do not want to move the posts on either level.[image: Building Plan]

Answer (score 5):

The posts do not *have to* line up- structures can certainly be designed and engineered that way.

Is this OK for your project ? There is no way that anyone here can make that judgement with the information you have given. There are many other structural considerations when thinking of replacing a bearing wall with a beam (load, uplift, lateral forces, etc).

I am guessing you would like someone here to say that it will be just fine- and it very well might be OK.

**This is something you need to be sure of. It is really worth the time and money to have a proper evaluation done by a qualified engineer familiar with your local regulations.**

Comment: It is most certainly **required by law** that they have the structural modification designs approved by an engineer.  It would be part of the permitting process for the renovation.  If you tried to DIY this under the table and your house collapsed, assuming you survived, your insurance would pay nothing.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  What struck me as odd is that the two posts do not currently line up as I believe they should.  The house was built this way.  Which made me think they didn't need to be.

Comment: Very often the posts do not line up and are fine as long as the load gets transferred down properly (hence the steel beam I would guess). It appears that your house was designed this way. A properly designed and sized beam to replace the bearing wall should be fine too-  the concern would be any lateral (shear) which might be lost by removing the bearing wall. This would just need to be properly certified by someone who can do the calculations. It should be do-able but perhaps special brackets/ hardware on the post to beam to replace what is lost with the wall removal. Best of luck !

Comment: @user130845 It strikes you as odd because you are probably not an engineer and you probably don't understand how they come to the decision that one design is safe and another is not.  This is why it's required that this work is done by licensed engineers.